# Can't Drag/Zoom/Interact with Google Maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

E: Found the problem. I had * { width: 100%; height: 100% } at the top of my CSS file. This screwed up the entire map. Removing this solved the problem.

This is a problem that arose from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23787101/google-maps-api-mysterious-white-map-popup-upon-loading). With help I was able to remove the white box overlaying the map by adding a z-index to the CSS (still not sure why this happens); however, now I can't interact with the map at all.  I can't click+drag or zoom, and the Google watermark appears at the top of the map (and as far as I know it should be at the bottom).

Here is the problem in CodePen (click the second box from the left on the navigation bar at the bottom):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pcwir

I've tried many different things, but no matter what it is it just doesn't want to work when implemented in my code. I can get it to work on a separate HTML page, but that isn't ideal.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the CSS line

```
#content_2 .gm-style>div:first-child{z-index:initial!important;}
```

And add this to your CSS

```
.gm-style * {
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
}
```

That should fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you!! Worked perfectly! I was just starting to strip down everything to see if I could find the problem. Another question though: why does that fix it? Or better, why is this happening in the first place? E: I also notice that the map is still missing a few things - street view, the pan arrows, and the map type (map/satellite) in the upper right.

Comment: When you had it set to `#content_2 .gm-style>div:first-child{z-index:initial!important;}` the `:first-child` pseudo class was selecting only the first div within the parent div 'gm-style'. That first div was the Google link at the top of the map. Without the pseudo class it now selects all the child divs so they all have their z-index raised.

Comment: Hmmm. I see what you're saying about a few things missing... I'll look into it.

Comment: When I removed the width/height: 100% from the CSS everything shows up. Sometimes I have to drag the map a little first, but they do show. E: It seems to only happen with the buttons. I can click them, but initially they are invisible (only sometimes).

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that the problem isn't with the CSS pseudo selector. I've updated my answer to fix that actual problem.